# How to set content to expire at a specific time every day in Apache using mod_headers or mod_expires?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, apache-2.4

We currently set our JS and CSS to expire every 24 hours. We would like to set it to say every morning at 3AM?

I know that I can do that in [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersModule) using following directive.

```
 expires       @15h30m;
```

But we use Apache and wanted to know if there is a directive like the following (hypothetical).

```
Header set Expires "%d+1 03:00:00 GMT"
```

Comment: That's a very strange way to go about it. As for Apache it seems to have no such functionality.

Comment: As we do our releases in the night, It would work perfect for our users. I know it may have issues when your site is international, as long as the time is in the right time zone. It should work.